# Upgrading existing preloaded sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I want to upgrade my existing database. I have imported a preloaded database(stored in assets folder) which is created using Sqlite manager.
So previously it has 4 Tables (e.g. Table **A**,**B**,**C**,**D**),and I want to do the following operations

- I want to add columns in table **A**
- I want to add a new table **E**
- I want to add some extra data in table **B**

Note: I have already created a database using Sqlite manager and added extra data also in table **B**.

My question is how to upgrade the database for existing user ?

my code is for adding a column is as below :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old,
            int current_version) {

    if(version_old == 1){
        mySqliteDb.execSQL("ALTER TABLE A ADD columnName TEXT ");
    }
}
```

So basically I am stuck in 2nd and 3rd problem.

There are few same type of question I found here , however what I need is an example.
Thank you.

Comment: For table E you just need to make a 'create table' statement. What kind of date you want to add to B?

Comment: @MD1948 In table **B** already some data (it contains three column) , I want to add some more data to it

Comment: More columns or fill the existing ones?

Comment: fill the existing ones

Answer (score 1):

For table E you just need to make a create table statement and for table B you need an insert statement without a where part to fill the existing columns.

Comment: Can't I directly map a table  created using sqlite manager ?Beacause there are thousands rows of data.

Comment: No, the manager itself doesn't know which tables you already created.